# How do I configure two 16:10 monitors that are in portrait orientation to act as a single 5:4 monitor in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have two **WUXGA** 16:10 monitors in portrait orientation that are put side by side next to each other. My laptop provides HDMI and VGA ports and it came with an Intel HD 620 and a discrete Nvidia GTX 950M.

- One monitor is connected to the HDMI port and the other to the VGA port.
- The bottom part of the bezel is wider so one of the monitors is set in Windows 10 as portrait (bottom bezel to the left), and the other is set in portrait flipped (bottom bezel to the right).

I would like to define a single 5:4 "monitor" that is composed of both monitors. I have already used Windows 10 options to extend the desktop but they are still treated as two separate monitors. On the Intel HD Graphics control panel, there is an option that is called "**collage**" where I can tell the system that the monitors are arranged in a vertical position and it creates a single "display". But the problem is that it doesn't take into consideration that one of them is in portrait flipped mode so in that monitor the image is flipped and doesn't match with the other.

The idea here is that if I set a particular program (like VLC), or video game to “full screen”, I want the image to stretch both physical monitors as one single image. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Nvidia Surround](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/technologies/surround/) should be able to achieve what you describe.

[Eyefinity](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/eyefinity) is AMD's version.

I'm not sure if those technologies are still prevalent/supported given the emergence of ultrawide monitors.

It looks like a paid program called [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/new-user-function-span-window-across-all-monitors-not-working/?ID=90c3d813-446d-4930-8242-481d8cb8cbe5) can do it too.